# Android GC internals

Tags: android, garbage-collection

Just want to make it 100% clear.

Android OS use 2 GC algorithms - Mark&Sweep and Concurrent Mark&Sweep.

Before 2.3 there was no concurrent algorithm - just a serial one.

Serial Mark&Sweep - is compacting algorithm and only work with Young generation.

CMS works with both generations(Yong and Old) and it's not compacting, just uses free lists. Also, there is no PermGen space in Android. In general, CMS works with Old generation, because Young is already cleared by serial algorithm.

Am i right ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before **Android 5.0**,there was no **compacting GC**,Dalvik VM only implement **Mark&Sweep** GC(and this can be **concurrent**,so your statement is not accurate for CMS is also an Mark&Sweep GC) and **Copying** GC,and used either of them depending on different situations(sorry that I don't know much about when to use which algorithm).

And Android 5.0 ART introduces 3 **compacting GC**:Semi-Space（SS）GC,Generational Semi-Space（GSS）GC and Mark&Compact GC(MC).Since the compacting GC is not as efficient as Mark&Sweep but can dispose memory fragments which the latter cannot,compacting GC is used as **background GC** while Mark&Sweep is used as **foreground GC**.

Comment: Yep, with introduction of ART, documentation slightly improved, as well as GC itself. I think the most important is that we finally have generations (hello short-living objects) and compacting support (hello bitmaps processing). However, I wish Renderscript be used more often to get optimal vectorization & memory usage